# How to exclude duplicates when counting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Say I have data like below:

```
id, dateVisited
1   3/4/2019  --Monday
1   3/4/2019  --Monday
1   3/5/2019  --Tuesday
2   3/4/3019  --Monday
2   3/5/2019  --Tuesday
2   3/7/2019  --Thursday
3   3/7/2019  --Thursday
4   3/5/2019  --Tuesday
5   3/8/2019  --Friday
```

How would I get the count of visits per day but only counting a specific `id` **at most 1 time** per given day.  So for the data above it should return:

```
day, visits
2    2     --show 2 here instead of 3 because ID 1 visited twice on 3/4
3    2
5    2
6    1
```

I can get the raw totals by doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable group by DATENAME(dw,dateVisited)
```

but I can't quite figure out how to exclude duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,dateVisited), COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY DATENAME(dw, dateVisited)
```